# Residue at $z=\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm a bit confused at when to use the calculation of a residue at $z=\infty$ to calculate an integral of a function.

Here is the example my book uses: In the positively oriented circle $|z-2|=1$, the integral of $$\frac{5z-2}{z(z-1)}$$ yields two residues, which give a value of $10\pi i$ for the integral, using the Cauchy Residue Theorem. I've got that down.

The book later, calculates the residue at infinity, yielding the same answer... - one residue calculation!

I can't seem to find what I'm missing here... Why is it that when considering this one bound, $2 \lt |z-2|\lt\infty$, we can use the residue at infinity to find the value of the integral... yet at the same time calculate a residue in three different bounds using the Cauchy Integral Theorem and find the same integral value?

Thanks!

Comment: The integral can be computed by the sum of the residues outside of the curve; in this case, there is only the one at infinity. As you can see, the sum of all the residues is $0$ (for any function with finitely many singularities on the Riemann sphere). There are many curious identities you can derive in this way.

Comment: Did you mean $|z-1|=2$? The circle you wrote down doesn't contain the pole at $z=0$ and goes through the pole at $z=1$.

Comment: to extend the excellent comment by @user8268: you can perform the variable substitution $u=z^{-1}$ which interchanges the outside and the inside of the contour. Then you can calculate the "usual" residue at the origin.

Comment: Joriki, actually it's |z|=2! I grabbed the other circle from a nearby example... Thx!

Comment: @user8268: That's interesting... is there a reason why, in a nutshell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your main question

> **When can you use the residue at $\infty$ to calculate the value of an integral $\int f$ ?**

is basically given by the following result.

> If $f$ is a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$, except for isolated singularities at $a_1, a_2, \dots , a_n$, then 
>   $$\operatorname{Res}{(f; \infty)} = -\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \operatorname{Res}{(f; a_k)} $$

were the [residue at infinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity) is defined as in the wikipedia article. Now, from [Cauchy's residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) it follows that

$$\operatorname{Res}{(f; \infty)} = -\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma} f(z) \, dz $$

where you can take $\gamma$ to be a circle $|z| = R$, where $R$ is large enough so that all the singularities $a_k$ are contained inside the circle. Of course you can then use the more sophisticated versions of Cauchy's integral theorem to change the curve $\gamma$, but this one suffices for simplicity.

Then the last formula gives you a way to calculate a complex integral just by calculating the residue at infinity of the function, instead of computing all the "finite" residues.

---

Now to answer your second question of why this is the case, maybe a sketch of a proof of this result will be enough.

So let $\displaystyle{F(z) := -z^{-2}f(z^{-1})}$, then since $f(z)$ is holomorphic for $|z| > R$ for some large enough $R$, we see that $F(z)$ is holomorphic for $|z^{-1}| > R$, or equivalently, for $0 < |z| < \frac{1}{R} $. Thus $F$ has an isolated singularity at the origin, and then by the definition of the residue at infinity we have

$$
\operatorname{Res}{(f; \infty)} :=  \operatorname{Res}{(F; 0)} = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|w| = \frac{1}{R}} F(w) \, dw = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|w| = \frac{1}{R}} -\frac{f(w^{-1})}{w^2} \, dw
$$

Then by making the substitution $z = \frac{1}{w}$ we get

$$
 \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|w| = \frac{1}{R}} -\frac{f(w^{-1})}{w^2} \, dw = \mathbf{\color{red}{-}}  \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z| = R}  \, f(z) dz
$$

where the last negative sign comes from the fact that the new circle $|z| = R$ you get after the substitution has its orientation reversed. And this last equality is precisely what we wanted to prove.

**Note**

This result is exercise 12 in section V.2 in Conway's book Functions of One Complex Variable I (page 122), or it also appears in exercise 6 in section 13.1 of Reinhold Remmert's book Theory of Complex Functions (page 387), in case you want some references.

Comment: Thank you! I like that I can avoid using the Cauchy residue theorem. What if at least one singularity lies ON the given circle, can I still use this theorem? Yes, yes, I think I can. Right? So, for an integral of (z^5)/((1-(z^3)) it would be more prudent to find the value using the residue at z=0 in the integrand of (1/(z^2))f(1/z) - where C is positively oriented circle |z|=2?